# HttpListener not receiving remote requests, even with the firewall down and all prefixes registered

Tags: c#, .net, windows, amazon-web-services, httplistener

I've written a server using HttpListener that works perfectly well for requests sent from the same computer, but doesn't even receive requests sent from a remote machine. I've tried using (including registering with netsh) the following prefixes: http://*:8080/, http://+:8080/, http://localhost:8080/, and the specific IP address of the host computer followed by port 8080.  (I also made sure no other applications were using 8080.) I opened up the appropriate ports in the firewall, and when that didn't work, I turned off the firewall just to see if it was a firewall issue and that also had no affect on the problem.  I have no idea what to try next, please help!

Also, the machine running this web service is a Amazon Web Services Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 with SQL Server Express and IIS EC2 instance.

Comment: Is port 8080 added to Security Group of your EC2 instance ?

Comment: @shashankaholic Good call!! No it wasn't, and adding it solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future users, the solution in more detail was to add an Inbound Custom TCP rule that included port 8080 in the 'Port range:' to a Security Group used by my EC2 instance.

- thanks to @shashankaholic for pointing that out

Answer (score 1):

If you are using AWS free tier EC2 instance, adding the given public elastic IP as the prefixes will not work for you even after you have the local firewall port and ports in security group opened. The HTTPListener needs to be bind with the public DNS provided by AWS. Then only it will work.